# How do I replace quotes with new line in sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have .txt file and I want to change quotes with new line.

I tried

```
sed "s/"/\\n/g" my_file.txt
```

and it shows me that " Unterminated quoted string "

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `tr`:

```
tr '"' '\n' < my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr` for this.

```
tr '"' '\n' < my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat test.txt | sed "s#\"#\\n#g"
```

Answer (score 0):

using sed

```
cat your_filename | sed 's/\"/\n/g'
```

using tr

```
 tr '"' '\n' < your_filename
```